# convert datagridview value to int

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I am getting value from cell within `datagridview` as below and I am convert that value to `int` first I used the 'Convert.ToInt32' and I get error that says

> Input string was not in a correct format.

I searched and found that I have to use `int.tryParse`

```
ImgId = Int32.TryParse(DGV_PatientImages.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[4].Value, out ImgId);
```

but I got an error saying

> The best overloaded method match for 'int.TryParse(string, out int)'
>   has some invalid arguments

```
int ImgId = 0;
```

so I tried to user (int) Specified cast is not valid

```
ImgId = (int)DGV_PatientImages.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[4].Value;
```

and I got

> Specified cast is not valid

```
DataGridViewRow dgvrow = DGV_PatientImages.CurrentRow;
if (dgvrow.Cells["DGV_PatientImages_ID"].Value != DBNull.Value)
{
    ImgId = Convert.ToInt32(DGV_PatientImages.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[4].Value);
}
```

any advice please

Comment: DataGridView columns are typed (or will be if the DGV creates them).  The cell type will be object (always) but inside will be a Dates, Int or whatever waiting to be cast.  It would appear that the one in question got created as the default TextBox/string type

Answer (score 0):

Well `DGV_PatientImages.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[4].Value` is a type that can not be cast to int. It is not a string.

By the following line of code, you can simply get what its type is:

```
string type = DGV_PatientImages.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.GetType().ToString();
```